# Tree number of levels

Tags: c, tree

I wrote a tree in which each node has a list of his children. So my questions are : How can I compute the number of levels of my tree? Can anyone give me some documentation about this ?. Thank you :).

Comment: What did you try ? Do you have some code ?

Comment: Please post your code first.

Comment: With computing the number of levels do you mean the depth of all levels, the average depth, what depth you're at when looping through it or the depth per children? You need to be more specific

Comment: I have no idea how to do this :). If it were a binary tree, it would have been easy to compute the number of levels.

Comment: I just want to see what is the depth of the tree .

Answer (score 0):

There could be different ways to solve this issue. One solution could be like count the nodes using a counter variable and increment the counter until the leaf node reaches. But you have to take care of

```
1. Longest Chain
2. Redundancy in couting
```

Second if each node has a list of children then count the nodes through this list present in root node.

A very appropriate way would be to define a variable by name **Level** into the **struct node**

```
typedef struct node {
...
Other members
...
int node_level;
} NODE;
```

and initialize it with 1 when root or any other node is created. Then update its value on each insertion into the tree.

By doing so you can see the level of any child tree, whenever you need to find. Also note each inserted node would have a level 1 and its ancestors will have greater level.